# How can I know what kind value will a function returns without executing the function itself?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

This is my decorator. I want any function that has this decorator to be checked if `_kwargs["_dir_abs"]` is an absolute path or not. If not I want to fault the `_function` by returning `False` if the decorated `_function` returns `bool`. And returning `None` if the `_function` returns anything other than `bool`.

The thing is `_function` is a folder operation (deleting, moving, naming, ...) hence I cannot just try it to see what it returns.

```
def check_abs_dec(_function):
    def wrapper(*_args, **_kwargs):
        if not check_abs(_kwargs["_dir_abs"]):
            napw()
            """`return False` if the `_function` return `bool`. `return None`
            if the `_function` return anything other than `bool`.
            """

        return _function(*_args, **_kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

Is there anyway I can check what value `_function` will be returned without actually executing it? Is there any workaround?

Comment: Have you try the function type?    print(type(_function(*_args, **_kwargs))

Comment: No, it executes `_function`. I have check it but without the decorators, http://pastebin.com/nAafWpks.

Comment: I don't get why this is get downvoted tbh :(.

Comment: This is a special case of the Halting Problem.. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try annotating your function with return type.

```
def do_not_call() -> bool:  # Note the `-> bool` part
    raise Exception("Do not call, may have side effects")
```

Now you can get return type using [`__annotations__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#types-and-members) attribute.

```
print(do_not_call.__annotations__['return'] == bool)  # True
print(do_not_call.__annotations__['return'] == int)  # False

def mysterious():  # Return type is not annotated...
    raise Exception("Do not call this either")
print(mysterious.__annotations__['return'])  # ...so this raises KeyError
```

This does however require you to annotate return type of all functions which return type you want to check.

To be honest, I also don't know when it was added to Python, but it works for me with Python 3.5.

If you are hardcore programmer who has plenty of time, I think you can use [`ast` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) to check bytecode of function for `return` statements and guess types. I don't recommend it though.

Comment: This is what I need! Thank you so much!

Comment: what is the name of "->" notation in Python (what people usually call that sign with)?

Comment: @notalentgeek I don't know :/ This is described in deatil at https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#abstract but I couldn't find any official name for this arrow :(

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot do this *by definition*. This is how dynamic languages work; you cannot know what type will be returned until you execute the function.

Comment: Alright, so what is the work around? My current solution is to create two __exactly__ the same decorator just to change the `return` to either `False` or `None` in case the `if` statement fails.

Comment: I can't tell you a workaround because I don't really understand what you want to do. If you know enough to use a different decorator, you must already know that the function will return a different type.

Comment: I know what my function will return into. Is just that I have this decorator that will be attached into to functions that will return `bool` or an object.